# How to remove these letters at the top of the page

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

Today I found that my Wordpress website has encountered a problem. There are two unexpected letters at the top of the page which can be found in the screen shot below. I can't find where it is from the raw files of Wordpress. I don't know what happened. Could somebody help me please?

[image: website screenshot]

[image: codes reviewer from Chrome]

Comment: Shouldn't there be `2 n`s in HTML? Also if its in your markup, can you not just delete them?

Comment: it comes from something that displays text while the page is still in the building of the header, causing the html page to close the `head` tag and open the `body` (the title tag should not be in the body).. intuition tells me that it wanted to display `\n` (new line) but the `\` dropped (not sure of that)

Comment: does it show without the admin bar present too?

Comment: I cant see the n's after visiting the site. check if you see them after loging out of the wp-admin. if not it mean these are in the admin files of wordpress.

Comment: I see only one `n` when loading the page (appeared/quick disappeared), and saw it here `</script>n<title>`in source

Comment: This is due to some code somewhere echoing out (displaying) those characters. It's mostly likely something in the functions file or a plugin. Try disabling all plugins to see if the characters still appear. Then reprot back here.

Comment: Still cant find where is wrong. Sad.

Answer (score 0):

Heya :)You might be using some website screenshot plugin. Deactivate that plugin and then check the output. :)

Answer (score 0):

i've had the same problem a while ago only instead of an n or two n's in your case i had a v just at the same place as yours is. What helped for me where the following steps.

1. Check all files, `header.php`, template files, etc.
2. Deactivate and activate your plug-ins. Maybe even try the Wordpress Re-install function from the updates page. Don't worry none of your contents like pages, posts, etc will be lost.
3. Check your `widgets`, `sidebars` and other content blocks from the back-end but also the corresponding template files.
4. If you have a decent editor like in my case PHPstorm make use of the `show history` function. It makes searching a lot easier.

I hope just like i had your problem will be solved after taking these steps.